# javac invalid flag

Tags: java, build, javac, matlab-deployment

I was trying to execute this command in command prompt to find my build error. What I have broken down upto is that javac is treating one of the file name as a flag (option) and thats why its not able to execute. HOw do i fix this?

```
C:\Users\AUG>javac -verbose -classpath "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\j
avabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar" -d "C:\Users\AUG\Documents\SourceTraceJAVA\Sourc
eTrace\src\classes" "C:\Users\AUG\Documents\SourceTraceJAVA\epanet2.h" "C:\Users
\AUG\Documents\SourceTrace\src\SourceTrace\SourceTrace.java" "C:\Users\AUG\Docum
ents\SourceTraceJAVA\SourceTrace\src\SourceTrace\SourceTraceMCRFactory.java" "C:
\Users\AUG\Documents\SourceTraceJAVA\SourceTrace\src\SourceTrace\SourceTraceRemo
te.java" "C:\Users\AUG\Documents\SourceTraceJAVA\SourceTrace\src\SourceTrace\pac
kage-info.java"
javac: invalid flag: C:\Users\AUG\Documents\SourceTraceJAVA\epanet2.h
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

It is considering epanet2.h file as a flag instead of a file. Is there somethng wrong with the syntax ? 
How do I resolve this?

Comment: What's this `.h` file? A C/C++ header file?

Comment: yeah.. It is a C/C++ header file.

Comment: How do you expect to use a C/C++ include file in the javac compiler?

Comment: If it's a C/C++ header file, why are you feeding it into the Java compiler?

Comment: @Kal - the output directory for class files (this information is also available from the documentation for javac)

Comment: Yes, because your -d options is followed by n quoted whitespace separated items.  The second such item "...\epanet2.h" is not considered as an additional term for the -d option (which is looking for just a single directory for class outputs).  Question (javac's and mine) is: what is the .h header file?

Comment: Well.. I was building a jar form MATLAB. THE jar needs a DLL and a header file. So I added them in the package and tried building a jar. and thats when this error is happeneing.

Comment: @Nick - `javac` does not build a jar, `jar` builds a jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't know what to do with `.h` files -- that looks (based on extension) like a C header file so it shouldn't be included in the list of files passed to `javac` or if it is a valid java source file then change its extension to `.java`.

Comment: I want to pack the DLL and header file along with the java files in that jar. How else could I include the header in that jar?

Comment: You can still specify them as parameters to the `jar` command -- but not to the `javac` command. `javac` compiles the code, `jar` packages them.

Comment: Can anyone show syntax as to how to compile the code first and then pack them in jar later? That would be really helpful. I m struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: you need to execute javac first to compile your code -- syntax here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html then you execute jar to package the compiled code -- syntax here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html

Answer (score 0):

`*.h` is not a valid java source file extension.